# return type of operator+= while overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have gone through some examples in the internet for operator overloading where the return type of `operator+=` is `T&`. Since we can't chain `+=` like `T a = b = c;` is it okay to declare the return type as `void`. When using `void` everything seems to work correctly. Is there any situation we have to avoid it?

For ex:

```
class MyInteger{
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        MyInteger(const int& a):x(a){}
        void operator+=(const MyInteger& rhs){
            x += rhs.x;
        }
};

MyInteger a(10);
a += a;  //No need to return anything because we can't chain
a = a + (a += a);
```

Comment: "Since we can't chain `+=`"? Why not? `(((a += b) += c) += d)` or `a += (b += (c += d)))`. It is as chainable as it ever gets.

Comment: @AnT Yeah ok, but we don't need to return anything, I guess. Because the changes are made in the LHS and it will be available for the next operation. So no need of `T&` as return.

Comment: But if you want to chain it, you *have* to return something.

Comment: @AnT You are right, getting `error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('void' and 'MyInteger')` if return is void.

Comment: @jblixr -- Why go against convention?  `operator+=` should be returning a reference to the current object. `MyInteger& operator+=(const MyInteger&);`  In addition, you have `operator +` available to you by implementing it in terms of `+=`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I didn't expected chaining as AnT said, so I thought that it is safe to go against convention. Now I understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another reason why you would want `operator +=` to return a reference to the current object is when you want to overload `operator +`.  Since you're writing an integer class, it won't make a lot of sense if `+=` were available, but `+` wasn't.

Here is what `operator +` would look like:

```
MyInteger MyInteger::operator+(const MyInteger& rhs)
{
   MyInteger temp(*this);
   return temp += rhs;  // <-- Uses operator +=
}
```

The above could not work (or even compile) if `operator +=` didn't return a reference.

Comment: Seperate `return temp += rhs;` statement otherwise it copies instead of NRVO.

Answer (score 3):

As @Ant already pointed out, it *can* be chained, but it's not the only consideration. Consider

```
cout << (a += b);
```

for example - this won't work if there is no return.

The arithmetic operators themselves are nothing more than a human convention. Technically, you can even have `+=` do `-=` - it will build and possibly run for you (as long as you follow your new private conventions). Within C++, you should follow the conventions of the language: the clients of your code will expect that `+=` self increments, and that

```
cout << (a += b);
```

will print out the result.

Answer (score 0):

what nobody has mentioned is that this chaining behavior contradicts mathematical precedent. j += o += e will be evaluate such that j is incremented not by o as you would expect if equivalent binary chains were performed left to right, but as though we had written j += (o += e). Equivalent binary operations where order matters such as subtraction are always read left to right and discreetly in the absence of parenthesis. 5-4-3 is -2 and not 1. I have yet to see an explanation for why this isn't considered a design flaw. C++ seems to make a habit of leaving rabbit holes where anyone might hope for terra firma.

also cant reply yet, but the idea of using a += operator to overload the + operator seems a little hair-brained to me, idk.